# Giving a user permission to modify/edit/delete files in “/” directory (Not using Terminal, but with File Explorer)

Tags: permissions, terminal, raspbian

I'm currently having an issue trying to give a user the permissions that the 'root' user has, which is to modify anything in the `/` directory. I've changed the `/etc/passwd` file but still no luck. I've also went into `visudo` and did the `pi ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, and that still didn't solve my issue.

Comment: What did you change in /etc/passwd?  When you added the `pi` entry to the sudo config file, what command did you then run to try and achieve what you wanted to (i.e. to create, edit or delete a file?) and what error did you get.

Comment: I didn't run any command @EightBitTony, I tried editing/modifying/deleting a file in the "/" directory and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

possibly a duplicate of [start file manager in terminal window wheezy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228801/start-file-manager-in-terminal-window-wheezy)

depends on your file manager. for example, run from terminal:

```
sudo pcmanfm &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm wanting. I just want to give a user access to edit in the "/" directory. Each time I try to modify a file it always gives me a permission denied unless I'm on root. I want the same permissions as root and don't want to have to sign in as root user every single time I want to put a file or files into that directory.

Comment: ok, sorry. Have you looked into [raspberry's documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md) on root  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL and
bob   ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL ?